# Designing DataSource Connection for Concurrency

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, concurrency

This code below is the "base" servlet we use for our project:

```
public class MyServlet extends Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Connection conn;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void connectDB() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        // get database settings

        InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();

        DataSource ds =(DataSource)cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDB" );
        conn = ds.getConnection();      
    }

    protected void closeDB() throws SQLException {
        try {
            if (conn!=null) conn.close();
        }
        finally {
            conn = null;
        }
    }

    protected void addCacheControl(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    }

}
```

For example `SomeServlet extends MyServlet` ...

Now `SomeServlet` is access in the browser it do a `forward()` to a JSP page then it refresh for a certain period (say 10 sec.)

After a while that the page is open, this code throws NullPointerException:

```
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_someSP(?, ?, ?)}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use instance fields of a Servlet like this, because it will be shared by multiple threads.

You need to explicitly pass the connection around as parameters and local variables through your program (so that they live on the stack, and each thread gets their own version), or maybe use a ThreadLocal if you want a more "global" approach. A ThreadLocal Connection can also be reliably closed by a ServletFilter when your request is done.

Comment: you mean from the 'SomeServlet' I should not access the 'conn'... like stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_someSP(?, ?, ?)}"); ?

Comment: No, I mean, the `conn` field should not exist at all. It should be a local variable or a ThreadLocal.

Comment: Ok, however SomeServlet works most of the time; the conn is just null sometimes

Comment: I mean when the servlet is accessed simultaneously in multiples tabs in a browser

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly the problem here. Your code is not thread-safe. If you want to make it work more than "most of the time", you need to get rid of the non-thread-safe shared state.

Comment: When you say local variable you mean variable inside function?